# why does the quran call the moon a light? and why do many translators and people who argue defending islam add the word "Reflection" in the verse

Tags: quran

its been causing me depression and I started struggling to even sleep properly. Its been concerning me ever since i got ambushed by non muslims when i was tryng to spread islam

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that it is helpful to add all necessary information like verses you refer to in your post to get a helpful answer a minimum reuqirement to get a good answer is to post a well elaborated question (See [ask]). For example [verse 5 in surat Yunus](https://legacy.quran.com/10/5) actually shows how exact Arabic language is because it distinguishes between the sun as the source of light and the moon as a reflector of light.

Answer (score 2):

The moon is called a light because it *is* a light. Go outside some night when the moon is full, and tell me otherwise: It's providing light.

The Qur'an isn't a scientific doctrine, it's a book of guidance. If it was Allah's will to communicate with some type of complex scientifically accurate legalese, He could surely have done that. But when He chooses to communicate in the Qur'an using simple terms and metaphors, he's communicating to the people — in this case the seventh-century Arabs — in simple terms that they can understand, in a language that they know, because *that's how people communicate*.

The real question is, why are *you* letting non-Muslims tell you what classic Arabic words mean, or letting them teach you your religion? I doubt they're any more fluent in the language than you. Who are they to decree that you're not allowed to use the Arabic word for "light" unless it's a particular *type* of light that it generates itself by some sort of internal power source?

Answer (score -1):

The Quran, like other religious texts, reflects the historical and cultural context of its time. When the Quran was written, the scientific understanding of celestial bodies was far from what we know today. It was commonplace to describe the moon as a 'light,' reflecting the observable reality that the moon illuminates the night sky. The use of the word 'light' likely represents a poetic or metaphorical usage rather than a scientific statement.

As for the addition of the word 'reflection' in contemporary translations, this can be seen as an attempt to reconcile the text with modern scientific understanding. It's a common practice in many religions to reinterpret or reframe religious texts as our knowledge of the world evolves.